# Split values rewriting key and value in newline

Tags: awk

File1.txt

```
A   1   2   3
```

File2.txt

```
A   1
A   2
A   3
```

File 2 can be converted into File 1 using the following code (the first column is the primary key):

```
cat File2.txt| awk '{line="";for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) line = line $i " "; table[$1]=table[$1] line;} END {for (key in table) print key "\t" table[key];}' > File1.txt
```

How can one go back from the format in File 1 to File 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo "A   1   2   3" | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)printf("%s\t%d\n",$1,$i)}'
A   1
A   2
A   3
```